# Laravel Resource whenLoaded not working for hasOne & belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel-5

I have an Order module, with a relationship for customer:

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::class, 'id', 'customer_id');
}
```

My query to fetch order details is:

```
$orderResponse  = Order::find(1);
```

My Order Resource consists of:

```
'customer' => new CustomerResource($this->whenLoaded('customer'))
```

The expected result is that I should get all customer details without customer object as I did not load it while fetching order data, but it's included in the response.

While loading collections it is working fine but not for a `hasOne()` relationship.

Comment: Are you trying to get customers which have orders ? Like this $orderResponse = Order::find(1); $orderResponse->customer()->id ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro  got it.
Actually that is the only problem.
I am using $order->customer->name;
In the same resource, so whole customer resource loading.
Thanks

Comment: Did you problem resolved ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro yes.

Comment: Can you check my answer as resolved ? if it does resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$orderResponse = Order::find(1); 
$orderResponse->customer()->id; //Customer Order Relationship
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **whenLoaded**, try using **when** for your hasOne relationship in your Order resource :

```
'customer' => $this->when($this->customer, new CustomerResource($this->customer))
```

If your customer relation is not empty, it will be loaded with your CustomerResource.

Comment: work with belongsTo relationship as well